# Tomcat7 pointing to a symbolic link WAR

Tags: linux, tomcat, symbolic-link, tomcat7, symlink

I have Tomcat7 running on a Linux server. Tomcat is pointing to a symbolic link WAR for my application. The link is pointing to the actual WAR. I am looking to upgrade the app. What I have done is placed a new WAR file of the upgraded app and made a symbolic link pointing to the new WAR. I am planning on doing mv newsymlink oldsymlink to overwrite the keep the same name for the symbolic link but point to the new WAR. After I do this, will Tomcat pickup the change automatically and load the new WAR or do I have to restart Tomcat?

Comment: What did you try? Why do you use symbolic link in this case?

Comment: That is the way the server is set up already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change the target of the existing symbolic link under /tomcat/webapps using the command:

```
ln -sf NEW_TARGET.war CURRENT.war
```